# How to group by more than one field in Drupal view?

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-6

Currently, grouping allows only one field in:

```
  Views > Basic Settings > Style Options > Grouping Field
```

Is there a way to group by two or more fields in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly in Views > Basic Settings > Style Options > Grouping Field, but there are ways around it, mainly by using the http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view module.  Check out http://drupal.org/node/843936 for more discussion on this topic.